# How to display a contents from an Array List in a string?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am a beginner at using java and I do not know how to get the system to output the contents from my array list in a string

```
private void createRooms()
{
    Room townCenter, boots, tesco, library, home;

    // create the rooms
    townCenter = new Room("in the town center", contents);
    boots = new Room("in boots drug store", contents);
    tesco = new Room("in tesco's", contents);
    library = new Room("in the city library", contents);
    home = new Room("at home", contents);
```

note where it says 'contents' I am trying to display the items in said room.

this is where I have started my Array List

```
milk = new Objects("milk");
paracetamol = new Objects("paracetamol");
book = new Objects("book");
money = new Objects("money");

tesco.addObjects(milk);
boots.addObjects(paracetamol);
library.addObjects(book);
home.addObjects(money);
```

the Array List itself is in a different class and looks like this

```
public ArrayList<Objects> contents;
```

So what I am trying to do is have the system print out the contents of each room. Any help is welcome and appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should Override the toString() of your "Objects" which represent the contents of your rooms. This way you can give a friendly description to each "Objects".

Inside of your Objects class:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return "Object: " + objectName; //use whatever variable you store "Milk" or its name in
}
```

Then, you can Override your Room class's toString() method in order to provide your description of the room, which in your case you want to do by printing out all of the items in your "contents" ArrayList.

You can do this by doing the following in your Room class:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return "Contents in the room" + contents.toString();
}
```

An ArrayList has a toString method which will call the toString() method for each element in the list. Each element in our case is an "Objects" which we just overrode the toString() method for to print out exactly what we wanted.

Now when you call:

```
System.out.println(tesco)
```

It will output:

```
 Contents in the room:
 Object: Milk
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ArrayList` class inherits a `toString()` method that converts each element of the list to a string. Per [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html#toString()), it joins them all together using commas, and encloses the entire thing with square brackets (`"[]"`). If that format is good enough, you can simply use

```
contents.toString()
```

wherever you need a string representation of what's in the list.

Each element of the list is converted to a string using `String.valueOf(object)`, which in turn calls `object.toString()` if the object is not `null`. So if you want a nicer representation of each element, you'll need to override the `toString()` method of your `Objects` class.

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the toString() method in your Room class.

Here is an example of overriding a class's toString() method:

```
@Override
public String toString() 
{ 
    return "Name: " + this.name + ", Description: " + this.description + ", Type: " + this.type;
}
```

You can then call toString() on your ArrayList or pass it to System.out.println() which will call toString() on it in order to display it.

For example:

```
System.out.println(roomList);
```

where roomList is your ArrayList of Room objects.

ArrayList's toString() method iterates through the objects that it contains and calls each of their toString() methods in order to build a string that represents the ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

For a given `room`, you can list its contents through a loop:

```
String contentsAsString = "";
for(Objects object : room.getContents()) {
    contentsAsString += object.toString() + " ";
}

// Now you can use the string
Sysm.out.println("contentsAsString: " + contentsAsString);
```

You need to implement the `getContents` method to return the array list, and also to override `toString`in `Objects`class to return its name.

---

EDIT: I think the best option is to implement above code as a member of `Room`, so you can use it directly from any room:

```
public class Room ...
    public String getContentsAsString() {
        // Code above.
        return contentsAsString;
    }
}
```

Later:

```
String contents = room.getContentsAsString();
```

Answer (score 0):

While you are learning, why don't you try it like this. You have mentioned "any help is appreciated" :)

You can enhance this to do lots of stuff with the objects you are passing

So create an interface that has an abstract displayMessage.

Something like this,

```
public interface Content {
  public void displayMessage(String message);
}

public class Milk implements Content{
  public Milk(String message){
    displayMessage(message);
}
public void displayMessage(String message) {
    // You can do whatever you want with the message
    System.out.println(message);    
}
}// milk class ends here
```

// Do the same for the other contents - Paracetamol, Book and Money

// You are only passing one content per room.

```
Content milk = new Milk("milk");
Content paracetamol = new Paracetamol("paracetamol");
Content book = new Book("book");
Content money = new Money("money");
```

// Now pass the objects as parameter for Room

```
// you don't have a content for this - townCenter = new Room("in the town      center", );
boots = new Room("in boots drug store", paracetamol);
tesco = new Room("in tesco's", milk);
library = new Room("in the city library", book);
home = new Room("at home", money);
```